# Computer stuck on updating software while trying without installing. Can I safely power button it off?

Tags: live-usb, shutdown, update-manager, ubuntu-gnome

I decided to update software when I was trying out Ubuntu GNOME without installing. It got stuck on Preparing configuration of Firefox-locale-pt. Can I power button off the computer safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a *persistent* Live USB it is totally irrelevant what you do on the system, the next time you boot into Live USB (“trying out”) it will be the same vanilla Ubuntu from which you started.